# Is there an IP multicasting possible in nanomsg?

Tags: linux, zeromq, scalability, publish-subscribe, nanomsg

How can I achieve an IP Multicasting in nanomsg?

I know that in ZeroMQ messaging, the IP Multicasting is achieved through a Pragmatic General Multicast ( PGM ) protocol.

Is there any way in nanomsg to also achieve the IP Multicasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, not yet.

The currently latest release of the nanomsg ( being 1.1.2. in EoY 2017 ) does not yet have a confirmed support for either a **`pgm://`** or **`epgm://`** transport classes, as you might have known from ZeroMQ toolkit.